# A variant of a $L^1$ estimate for linear transport equation

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Consider $$u_t(t,x) + (a(t,x)u(t,x))_x = 0 \text{ for } (t,x) \in (0,\infty)\times \mathbb R$$
Assume $\|u\|_{L^\infty} < 1$.

Does some estimate like the following one hold?
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{|b|<1}\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{|u(t,x+b)-u(t,x)|}{|b|} dx db \lesssim \int_{\mathbb R} a_x(t,x) dx 
\end{align*}

This is motivated by having an intermediate step between $L^1$ and $BV$ estimates for linear transport.

Comment: It seems interesting. Can you please provide more contexts? For example, what’s the motivation of the problem?